# Inverse cumsum for numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, cumsum

A is a ((d,e)) numpy array. I  compute a ((d,e)) numpy array B where I compute the entry B[i,j] as follows

```
b=0
for k in range(i+1,d):
    for l in range(j+1,e):
        b=b+A[k,l]
B[i,j]=b
```

In other words, B[i,j] is the sum of A[k,l] taken over all indices k>i, l>j; this is sort of the opposite of the usual cumsum applied to both axis. I am wondering if there is a more elegant and faster way to do this (e.g. using np.cumsum)?

Comment: Could you give a small example with actual data and the expected outcome?! And you could also add the 'python' tag.

Comment: Something like `np.cumsum(np.cumsum(A[::-1, :], axis=0)[::-1, ::-1], axis=1)[:, ::-1]` will probably get you about 99% of the way there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to do this:

```
A = np.arange(15).reshape((5, -1))

def cumsum2_reverse(arr):
    out = np.empty_like(arr)
    d, e = arr.shape
    for i in xrange(d):
        for j in xrange(e):
            b = 0
            for k in xrange(i + 1, d):
                for l in xrange(j + 1, e):
                    b += arr[k, l]
            out[i, j] = b
    return out
```

Then if you do,

```
In [1]: A_revsum = cumsum2_reverse(A)

In [2]: A_revsum
Out[2]: 
array([[72, 38,  0],
      [63, 33,  0],
      [48, 25,  0],
      [27, 14,  0],
      [ 0,  0,  0]])
```

You could use `np.cumsum` on the reverse-ordered arrays to compute the sum. For example, at first you might try something similar to what @Jaime suggested:

```
In [3]: np.cumsum(np.cumsum(A[::-1, ::-1], 0), 1)[::-1, ::-1]
Out[3]:
array([[105,  75,  40],
       [102,  72,  38],
       [ 90,  63,  33],
       [ 69,  48,  25],
       [ 39,  27,  14]])
```

Here we remember that `np.cumsum` starts with the value in the first column (in this case last column), so to ensure zeros there, you could shift the output of this operation. This might look like:

```
def cumsum2_reverse_alt(arr):
    out = np.zeros_like(arr)
    out[:-1, :-1] = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(arr[:0:-1, :0:-1], 0), 1)[::-1, ::-1]
    return out
```

This gives the same values as above.

```
In [4]: (cumsum2_reverse(A) == cumsum2_reverse_alt(A)).all()
Out[4]: True
```

Note, that the one that utilizes `np.cumsum` is much faster for large arrays. For example:

```
In [5]: A=np.arange(3000).reshape((50, -1))

In [6]: %timeit cumsum2_reverse(A)
1 loops, best of 3: 453 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit cumsum2_reverse_alt(A)
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.7 us per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I figured an alternative is taking np.rot90(A,2) and then applying cumsum against both axes, though I haven't benchmarked it against your solution yet.